# An appropriate value for `item-indent` in tasks package

Tags: tasks

I have three examples of increasing functions that I have listed using the `tasks` package.  A value in the `\settasks{}` command is `item-indent=2cm`.  I want the left edge of `iii.)` to be indented `2em` from the left margin, though.  I set `label-width` equal to the width of `iii.)` and I have `label-offset=1em`.  I think that `item-indent` should be set equal to the sum of `2em`, the value for `label-width`, and `label-offset=1em`.  Is that right?  (I used `item-indent=3.5cm` just to give some indentation. It is not the indentation that I want.)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\newlength\labelwd
\settowidth\labelwd{ iii.)}
\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{counter-format =tsk[r].), label-offset=1em, label-align=right, label-width
=\labelwd, item-indent=3.5cm, before-skip =\smallskipamount, after-item-skip=0pt}


\begin{document}


The following functions are sums of two increasing functions on the interval $[0, \, \infty)$ and so are increasing functions on $[0, \, \infty)$.
\begin{tasks}(1)
          \task $x^{2} + x$
          \task $x^{3} + 2x^{2} + 3x - 7$
          \task $x^{2} + \sqrt{x}$
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\setlength\parindent{1em}

\newlength\labelwd
\settowidth\labelwd{iii.)}
\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{counter-format =tsk[r].), label-offset=1em, label-align=right, label-width
=\labelwd, item-indent=\dimexpr\labelwd+2em +\parindent\relax, before-skip =\smallskipamount, after-item-skip=0pt}
\begin{document}


The following functions are sums of two increasing functions on the interval $[0, \, \infty)$ and so are increasing functions on $[0, \, \infty)$.
\begin{tasks}(1)
          \task $x^{2} + x$
          \task $x^{3} + 2x^{2} + 3x - 7$
          \task $x^{2} + \sqrt{x}$
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: While waiting for a response, I tried `item-indent=\labelwd+3em`.  It seems to give me the same display.  Is there a difference?

Comment: There's none since I set `\parindent=1em`. But the value of `\parindent`  may depend on the class you load, and using it seems more relevant here (just in case).